# Sierra Upgrade Laravel/Homestead/Vagrant Problems?

Tags: laravel, vagrant, macos-sierra, homestead

I decided to do the upgrade and regretting it now so I am hoping to find someone else who might have experienced this in their environment.
 Everything seemed fine and I thought everything was working, my local web server works fine for plain HTML/CSS sites and Laravel Projects install correctly, everything works until I noticed something that initially I thought was not a huge deal but I think it is connected to the overall problem I'm seeing.
The first signal was when I do a git status when ssh'd into a site and though everything does what it should I get these warnings:

```
warning: unable to access '/home/vagrant/.config/git/attributes': Permission denied
warning: unable to access '/home/vagrant/.config/git/ignore': Permission denied
```

I can code, use composer, install, artisan works, I can deploy, I can clone repos, I can push and pull from repos and more basic sites are fine locally,  contact forms work.  Vagrant Up and Vagrant Halt works.  So I was disregarding at this time these warnings.

Now I have another project I am a team member of and this project I see a bigger problem.  I know it's not the code as all was fine under El Capitan locally and, all is fine on the dev and production servers.  it is a working piece of software.

But now after the Sierra update, I cannot locally, log in to the site on my local environment anymore, it redirects me back to the login page with no visible errors.  If I do the reset password link, the email doesn't send, there are no errors displayed and when the send email is clicked it just redirects to the login page.  If I try to register a new user, I am allowed to fill out all the information when I finish it just redirects to the login page, no email is sent, no errors are shown at all.

One thing I did find is that when I did php artisan route:list the output is as follows:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/Code/xxx$ php artisan route:list -v

        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh"     content="1;url=http://localhost/auth/login" />

        <title>Redirecting to http://localhost/auth/login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="http://localhost/auth/login">http://localhost/auth/login</a>.
    </body>
</html>
```

THE ABOVE HTML REPEATS 66 TIMES

(Continue Output)

```
    [RuntimeException]
      Session store not set on request.
```

Doing an exception trace I get this:

```
   > Exception trace:
         ()at/home/vagrant/Code/xxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php:870


Illuminate\Http\Request->session() at /home/vagrant/Code/xxx/app/Http/Controllers/RolesController.php:49
 App\Http\Controllers\RolesController->__construct() at n/a:n/a
 ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs() at /home/vagrant/Code/xxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:779
 Illuminate\Container\Container->build() at /home/vagrant/Code/xxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:629
 Illuminate\Container\Container->make() at /home/vagrant/Code/xxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:697
 Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make() at /home/vagrant/Code/xxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteListCommand.php:165
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand->getControllerMiddleware() at /home/vagrant/Code/xxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteListCommand.php:146
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand->getMiddleware() at /home/vagrant/Code/xxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteListCommand.php:118
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand->getRouteInformation() at /home/vagrant/Code/xxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteListCommand.php:88
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand->getRoutes() at /home/vagrant/Code/xxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteListCommand.php:75
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand->fire() at n/a:n/a
 call_user_func_array() at /home/vagrant/Code/xxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:507
 Illuminate\Container\Container->call() at /home/vagrant/Code/xxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:169
 Illuminate\Console\Command->execute() at /home/vagrant/Code/xxx/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:256
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /home/vagrant/Code/xxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:155
 Illuminate\Console\Command->run() at /home/vagrant/Code/xxx/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:794
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /home/vagrant/Code/xxx/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:186
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/vagrant/Code/xxx/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /home/vagrant/Code/xxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:107
 Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle() at /home/vagrant/Code/xxx/artisan:35
```

Oh, and if I do sudo apachectl configtest it returns "Syntax OK".

I don't know but suspect this is some kind of permissions error?  Perhaps with vagrant?  But I'm at a loss as to where to look, or how to fix.

I did a port scan on 127.168.10.10 and it shows:

```
 Open TCP Port:     22          ssh
 Open TCP Port:     80          http
 Open TCP Port:     443         https
 Open TCP Port:     1025        blackjack
 Open TCP Port:     3306        mysql
 Open TCP Port:     5432        postgresql
 Open TCP Port:     8025        ca-audit-da
```

All I know is I need to get Laravel/Vagrant/Homestead fixed so I can get back to work and after a week of research and finding bits and pieces to resolve I'm at a loss as to how to begin to get my laravel projects working to full potential, especially in the areas where they need the authorization.  Could it be a write issue? I am thinking everything is connected at this point but am hoping that someone who did the Sierra Upgrade in the last year might have some insight?

Any inputs or advice is welcome.  Unsure what else to share at this point to help diagnose.